# Error "IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device" AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

Yesterday I tried to use the command "sam build" in cloud9 and I received the error "IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device". Today I can't open cloud9.
I tried to restart the instance and it didn't work.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the EBS volume attached to your cloud9 instance:

Here are some guidelines:

1. Navigate to the Cloud9 Environments page.
2. Choose the desired environment and click "View details".
3. Proceed to EC2 Instance and select "Go To Instance".
4. Under the "Storage" tab, click on the respective Volume ID.
5. Choose the Volume, then click "Actions" on the upper right. Opt for "Modify volume".
6. Adjust the volume size to your preference and refresh the "Volumes" page.
7. Once modification is done, return to the "Instances" page and reboot the instance.
8. Wait approximately two minutes before reopening the Cloud9 environment.
9. To verify the changes, execute the following command: `df -h` You should now see a larger volume.